# What is the Best implementation of CRUD with JSF primefaces and Google App Engine Datastore

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jpa, jsf-2, primefaces

I have tried creating a CRUD application JSF primefaces, GAE and JPA. I have also tried it using standard GQL. But i still have not figured out the best way to go about it. Especially when doing edit and deleting of records presented on primefaces dataTable.

With @ViewScope i get an exception stating that a Google Data Store class is not serialized.

Please, what is the best way to use these technologies together...

Comment: Can you show us how do you actually do it? Paste some sample/pseudo code.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if your JSF implementation is compatible with Google App Engine ?

https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/WillItPlayInJava

> JSF 1.1 appears to be working out-of-the-box. JSF 1.2 and JSF 2.0 should also work if you set the com.sun.faces.enableMultiThreadedStartup context parameter to false to your web.xml file. Setting this parameter to false (it's set to true by default) will prevent additional threads from being spawned. For more information on running JSF 2.0 in App Engine, see this site.

Comment: I have followed all the configuration procedures... My only problem lies when i am trying to work with the Datastore for Edit and Delete